# Working out efficiently if points are within polygons for large datasets

Tags: matrices, polygons

Perhaps this question should be elsewhere but as its mainly a mathematical problem Im posting here.

I have a dataset of which looks like this:

```
[
  [ 242841.86914496083,
  1090.0027001134586,
  11711.344635666988,
  142639.20305005432 ],

  [ 212841.86914496083, 
  128007.0027001134586,
  11711.344635666988,
  142639.20305005432 ]
  ...
]
```

Each array is called an "event" and in this case have 4 "parameters". I want to plot these events on multiple scatter charts. For example, on the first scatter chart, i'll plot the first and second parameter of each event, so the (x, y) point for the first event is (242841.86914496083, 1090.0027001134586), for the 2nd event is (212841.86914496083, 128007.0027001134586) etc. On the second chart, i'll plot the second and third parameter of each event, so the (x, y) point for the first event is (11711.344635666988, 142639.20305005432), for the 2nd event is (11711.344635666988, 142639.20305005432) etc.

In the example Im giving the range is 0 to 262144;

The scatter charts are 200px x 200px but can be any pixel size up to 2000px. It's always square.

When plotting, I want to work out which points are within a polygon. Here is a sample polygon:

```
[
    [
        200000,
        100000
    ],
    [
        230000,
        180000
    ],
        [
        200000,
        200000
    ],
    [
        200000,
        230000
    ],
    [
        110000,
        220000
    ],
    [
        100000,
        180000
    ],
]
```

The points within the polygon are to be plotted in a different color to the points outside it. The polygon is to be applied to scatter chart 1 and 2, but it's the first and second parameter of each event that is to be used to figure out if the event is within the polygon and what color it should be on both charts. E.g. say the point for event 2 (212841.86914496083, 128007.0027001134586) are within the polygon, this mean that event will appear in red in each chart.

I have a simple algorithm which runs through each point and checks if it's within the polygon. I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/point-in-polygon.

Keep in mind, there are often multiple polygons (n), and these can be applied to different combinations of parameters. So I need to work out if an event is in all n polygons, or if its in n-1 polygons etc.

To sum up, what I need to know is:

- percentage of total events within each polygon
- number of events within a polygon
- number of events within n, n-1 etc polygons
- x value mean of event with polygon
- y value mean of event with polygon

My algorithm performs well for up to 10,000 events. But then it hits issues. Some of my users have files that contain 1 millions events, and my algorithms take minutes.

How can I work out what I need more efficiently? Binning data is an option but then I lose accuracy in results. E.g. for a 200 by 200 pixel image I could create 200 bins for each axis. Problem is a then lose accuracy on the x and y mean values. Also, users can change to 201 x 201 pixel images, now I need to work out 201 bins etc.

After file upload, these files are on the server and can be pre-processed before graphs are generated. Is there anything that can be done mathematically to improve performance for large number of events?

**EDIT:**
To be clear - figuring out if a point is in a polygon is not the most performance intensive. The most performance intensive part is looping through 1 million events in order to plot them on a, say, 400px by 400px image. The solution, probably lies somewhere in binning data - but if I make 400 bins, then the user - on the fly - changes the image size to 410px, I now need to make 410 bins from the ORIGINAL dataset. Is there some way around this?

**EDIT**
So the data is known in advance. This sits on my server and can be manipulated in anyway. The size of the image and the polygons are now knows in advance - users draw the polygons and the image must change on the fly. With, say, 1 million events, this is not possible - the browser usually crashes...I can bin the data, but if I create 200 bins (standard image is 200 x 200), then the user makes the image bigger e.g. 210 x 210, now I have to cycle through 1 million events and create 210 bins, which is obviously a big performance issue

Comment: Take a ray with the desired endpoint (with a slope not equal to any edge of the polygon) and see how many times it intersects an edge of the polygon within its vertices. If the number is odd, you are inside the polygon. This works for any polygon that doesn't intersect itself.

Comment: The real issue Im having is having to search through 1 million events for a graph of, say, 200 pixels. Thats what causes performance problem

Comment: It might speed things up if you first find the "bounding box" of each polygon (a rectangle with sides parallel to the axes).  Then if a point is not in the bounding box, it can't be in the polygon.

Comment: @awkward yes i should have mentioned im already doing that

Comment: I bet that the people over at cs.SE have already figured this one out. But I do have one idea that may or may not work. I will post it later today.

Comment: *The real issue Im having is having to search through 1 million events for a graph of, say, 200 pixels*. I don't understand something: isn't it rather $200\times 200=40000$ "square pixels"? How do you get down to $200$?

Comment: @fedja plotting 1 million points on 200 x 200 means many points will be plotted on the same pixel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that I would generically expect to give you a huge performance boost.  I can't quantify the performance boost without making additional assumptions (such as the probability distribution of the data points or the size/shape of the polygons).  But in realistic cases I would expect it to be much faster.

I'm going to make the following assumptions:

1. The polygons are *not* known in advance.
2. The dataset *is* known in advance.
3. The image resolution is *not* known in advance.  (You mentioned the user changing it suddenly.)

The current problem is that if there are $p$ polygons and $n$ data points, then the naive approach (testing every data point and every polygon independently) scales like $O(pn)$, so it's terrible when $p$ and $n$ are both large.  With the assumptions above, there isn't an obvious solution for slowing down the $p$ factor, but you can do something for the $n$ factor.

My suggestion basically amounts to binning information about the data, but in a resolution-independent way.

1. Before the user runtime, put the data points into a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).  This is a binary tree search structure that partitions the data into smaller and smaller geometric regions in a very generic way.  (Here, $k$ is the dimensionality of the space the points are in, so $k=2$.)
2. For every node in the tree, store two things:

   - The number of points belonging to that branch of the tree.
   - The bounding box of all of these points.
3. At runtime, iterate over all polygons and over the nodes in the tree.  For the node iteration, descend through the tree depth-first.  At each node, check whether the bounding box of the node is completely inside the polygon, completely outside the polygon, or neither.  (See step 4 for a suggested implementation.)  Use the following to respond to each case:

   - Completely inside the polygon: In this case, count all of the points on this branch of the tree as being inside the polygon and stop descending further into this branch.
   - Completely outside the polygon: Stop descending further into this branch.
   - Neither: Keep descending and repeat this check.
4. Suggested algorithm for checking containment of bounding box and polygon: For every edge $e$ in polygon $p$, check whether $p$ intersects any of the four sides of the bounding box.  If any of them do, immediately put this in the "neither" category (there is partial overlap between the $p$ and the bounding box).

   If there are no intersections, then the bounding box must be completely inside or completely outside of the polygon.  To decide which is which, you can check whether any point in the bounding box is inside or outside the polygon (which you already know how to do for a point).

   Three things to note about this item:

   - I am not an expert at computational geometry and this part can probably be improved.
   - I am assuming that you have a function that can check efficiently whether two line segments intersect.  This is a problem that has been discussed elsewhere (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3838329/3023462)).
   - When you get to a leaf node of the tree, then the node corresponds to a point rather than a rectangle, which is much simpler to check.  (You might want to insert special handling for this; I'm not sure if it is worth it.)

The idea here is to prune off whole branches of the tree as soon as you possibly can.  I expect that this will give a huge speedup immediately, but it's hard to prove this.  If you don't see the speedup immediately and want to start investigating/profiling, then here are a few things to keep in mind.

- Depth matters.  Anything you can do to classify nodes further up the tree will help.
- If the polygons have a lot of edges, then the algorithm I proposed in (4) might be slow, and there might be a better one.
- The absolute worst-case scenario here is that you check all of the nodes in the tree.  There are about twice as many nodes as points, and the check that I am proposing is more expensive than the check for a single point, so the behavior would actually get worse.  But I cannot imagine this ever happening in a realistic case.  (You would have to draw a polygon that looks like a really long and winding snake that passes very close to every point.  Otherwise, there would be nodes that are classified as entirely inside or entirely outside of the polygon.)

Comment: Not quite sure I follow your solution, I have edited the question, the data IS known in advance - and therefore can be pre-processed be it binning or whatever - but polygons are draw on the fly on the image. Image size can be edited on the fly. Not sure how this affects your answer...

Comment: Oh ok. Totally different situation. I probably won’t have a chance to actually edit my answer until tomorrow evening, but very briefly, I think the solution is to put the data into a $k$-$d$ tree and then store the bounding box of each node in the tree. When calculating whether points are inside the polygons, use the binding box of the node instead of the points themselves. If the bounding box is completely inside the polygon, all of the points belonging to that node are inside the polygon. This could result in an enormous speedup (no longer $O(n)$.

Comment: thank you, im going to try this tomorrow

Comment: Ok great. There are probably some subtleties here to think about. The main missing thing is how to test efficiently whether a rectangle is completely inside/outside of a polygon. This isn’t a hard problem but it will requires more operations than testing a single point, so it needs to be implemented efficiently or else the slowdown from this will cancel out some of the speedup from reducing the number of points/nodes that need to be considered. But since each bounding box is a rectangle this is probably not too hard.

Comment: Ill attempt to put the data into a k-d tree this evening and ill update the question and you can take a look, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Mark Sorry it took me a while to reply.  Hopefully this helps!

Comment: thank you! Im going to go through all of this this evening and get back to you

Comment: The maximum image size is 1,000px x 1,000px. In the case of 1 million points, should I build the K-d tree from 1 million points, or first bin the data and build from the binned data?

Comment: The possible values of each axis are 0 - 262144 on each axis, so when i say bin I mean create 1,000 bins each 262122/1000 wide

Comment: The relationship between the pixelated image and the original data has never been completely clear to me. But there is presumably a reason why you are treating polygon containment on the original data rather than the pixelated image. (For example, perhaps the polygons can go through the middle of a pixel and you need the result to be accurate anyway.) The point of the tree is that you can test polygon containment on the original data just once, then store which nodes are contained in each polygon, in a way that is independent of the picture resolution. ...

Comment: ... (And the number of nodes you need to store should generally be far smaller than the number of data points.) This helps you if the user changes the resolution, because you already know which nodes are inside the polygon and don’t need to calculate this again. You just need to re-generate the image at a different resolution, and this should be quite fast.

Comment: Its actually a legacy issues. When I first created the app the number of events was <= 1,000. I need to provided stats like average mean x value within a polygon. So I calculated this on the original data, and this same algorithm drew the images. But now Im processing massive files, sometimes 800,000k, and its almost unusable. So i intend to separate calculating of stats (done on original data and using the k-d tree algorithm you suggest) and drawing the image (done after binning original into 1,000 bins - as max image size is 1000px)

Comment: Makes sense. Hope it fixes the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If the polygon is [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) then there is a simple solution.

Every convex polygon is created by the intersection of [half-planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-space_(geometry)).

A point can be determined to lie on a particular side of a half-line (the bounding line of a half-plane) if its line segment with a point known to be on the 'outside' fails or succeeds to [intersect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(Euclidean_geometry)#Two_line_segments) with the half-line.

If a point is 'inside' all the half-lines of the bounding (convex) polygon, it is inside the polygon.

Comment: I still have the issue of having to loop through 1 million points.....

Comment: If each point is different, you will do anyway. Computers these days are fast though, so 1million points should only take a couple of seconds at most..!

Comment: “now knows” -> “not known”, right?

Comment: @JMP is making the same point I am. Doing a million operations ($O(n)$ in the language of my answer) is easy if each operation is simple.  Finding whether the point is inside many complex polygons is not a simple operation though.